# Dotfuscator CE Build Error: External type not found System.Windows.Input.ICommand,PresentationCore

Tags: icommand, dotfuscator

I have an application targeting the .NET Framework 4.0.  It builds and runs fine but I cannot get it to compile in Dotfuscator CE and they will not support it since it is CE.  I am stuck.

Dotfuscator CE (v5.0.2500.0) with Visual Studio 2010 SP1.  This is the Error:

```
Resolving method references...
External type not found System.Windows.Input.ICommand,PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
Build Error.
```

The problem seems to originate from Microsoft changing ICommand from PresentationCore.dll in NET 4.0 to System.dll in NET 4.5.  Studio handles this and compiles fine as I am targeting NET 4.0.

Dotfuscator CE does not handle it and I am not sure how to correct the issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just ran into the exact same error.

Comment: Same issue here, but .NET 4.5 is not involved in the build (though it's installed on the system). And it used to work some time ago. Seems to be unreliable to use unsupported software in a productive process. Need to find a different tool...

Answer (score 3):

1. Find the path of .NET4's PresentationCore.dll, such as C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0
2. On Dotfuscator's setting tab -> User Defined Assembly Load Path;
3. Add PresentationCore.dll's path to the path list and check the Search first.

Hope it work for you.